# Move diagonally in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want move to a specific diagonal direction in netlogo.

I can move the turtle with the `fd` command but I don't know what condition (if-else) put in the code

```
    to go
     ask turtle 2 
       [ move ] 

  tick
      end

   to move 
    if( (pxcor = -15) and (pycor = -15 ))
 [fd  5     ]
    end
```

Comment: what does "Specific direction Diagonal" mean? what specific direction? how do you want that specific direction to be determined?

Comment: i want  turtle with id 2  ,first  move  to right and then move to up  and then stop, but in my code turtle with id 2 move randomly.

Comment: I cleaned up the question and title a bit. Please make sure you're being as clear as possible to make it easier for others to assist.

Comment: it is not possible to help you if you don't clearly express what your intentions are and what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still unclear.  You say you "want turtle with id 2 ,first move to right and then move to up".  But how far in each direction?  I'll assume 5, based on your question.  Here is what seems to be the best overall match to your question.

```
to go
  ask turtle 2 [move1]
end
to move1
  set heading 45
  fd 5
end
```

But if you really want to move right and then move up

```
to move2
  set heading 90
  fd (5 / sqrt 2)
  set heading 0
  fd (5 / sqrt 2)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help .but i want after  a one run my turtle stop.please help me.

Comment: Both `move1` and `move2` only move a turtle once.  If you do not want it to move again, the only use them once.  Note that `go` only calls `move1` once.  If you think it is calling it repeatedly, then you probably are calling `go` with a "forever button": see "Controlling the Model at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/tutorial1.htm